# Solution to an equation involving continued fractions and decimal expansion.

Tags: continued-fractions

Does there exist a positive real number $x$, whose decimal expansion is non-terminating, such that:

$\large \displaystyle x = \overline{a_0.a_1a_2a_3a_4a_5\cdots} = a_0 + \cfrac{1}{a_1 
          + \cfrac{1}{a_2 
          + \cfrac{1}{a_3 + \cfrac{1}{a_4 + \cfrac{1}{a_5 \, + _\ddots}} } } }$

$\large \displaystyle a_k$ maps each $\large k$  to a decimal digit.

I have not been able to find any references or similar topics out there on continued fractions.

My question also extends to arbitrary integer bases and possibly non-integer bases.

Comment: Must $x$ be positive ?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's significant, but sure.

Comment: Then, there is no example , at least in base $10$. No matter what $a_0$ is, $a_1$ must be $3$ and analyzing the numbers $0.31,\cdots,0.4$ shows that the continued fraction cannot coincide with the decimal representation. I did not work out the case, when $x$ is negative, but intuitively, I guess, there is no example either.

Comment: @Peter Analyzing the numbers how? The example [given in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2734886/167197) seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: @MikePierce The shown continued fraction contains a zero not being the first entry. Usually , this is ruled out.

Comment: [Trott Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrottConstant.html)